# Flask-Restful error: "as_view" method not inherited

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I am writting a RESTful API using the Flask framework and the Flask-RESTful plugin. I define my API classes on top of the `Resource` class that this plugin provides, as in the [examples](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api). However, when I want to register my classes using the `add_resource` method I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'UserAPI' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

The `as_view` method is part of the [Flask Pluggable Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/), this is, the `View` class. The `Resource` class is built on top of this class, and my `UserAPI` class on top of the `Resource` class. For this reason, the `as_view` method should be inherited, but it is not.

Any ideas on which could be the problem?

Here you can see how I defined the classes:

```
from app import api, db
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, abort
from models import *

class UserAPI(Resource):

    def get(self, user_id):
            user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id)[0]
            if user is None:
                    abort(404, message="User {} doesn't exist".format(user_id))

            else:
                    return {'user' : user}, 201

api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/api/v0.1/users/<int:user_id>', endpoint = 'user')
```

EDIT:

This the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/queries.py", line 35, in <module>
    api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/api/v0.1/users/<int:user_id>', endpoint = 'user')
  File "/home/app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 344, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 362, in _register_view
    resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint))
AttributeError: type object 'UserAPI' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Here you can see how the `View` and `Resource` classes have the `as_view` method, while my `UserAPI` class has not:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from flask.views import View
>>> inspect.getmembers(View, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
[('as_view', <bound method type.as_view of <class 'flask.views.View'>>), ('dispatch_request', <unbound method View.dispatch_request>)]
>>>
>>> from flask.ext.restful import Resource
>>> inspect.getmembers(Resource, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
[('as_view', <bound method MethodViewType.as_view of <class 'flask_restful.Resource'>>), ('dispatch_request', <unbound method Resource.dispatch_request>)]
>>>
>>> from app.queries import UserAPI
>>> inspect.getmembers(UserAPI, predicate = inspect.ismethod)
[('__init__', <unbound method UserAPI.__init__>), ('__repr__', <unbound method UserAPI.__repr__>), ('get', <unbound method UserAPI.get>)]
```

Comment: That's indeed a weird exception; time to add debug prints. `print dir(UserAPI)` would be a good one, as well as `print UserAPI.mro()`. Can you share the output of those two? A full trackback would be helpful too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After scanning the code I found that the `Resource` class inherits from the `MethodView` class of Flask. Well, finally I managed to get the `as_view` method by inheriting directly from the `MethodView` class instead of the `Resource` class. This is:

```
from app import api, db
from flask.ext.restful import abort
from flask.views import MethodView
from models import *

class UserAPI(MethodView):

     def get(self, user_id):
         user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id)[0]
         if user is None:
             abort(404, message="User {} doesn't exist".format(user_id))
         else:
             return {'user' : user}, 201

api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/api/v0.1/users/<int:user_id>', endpoint = 'user')
```

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 29):

I had this same issue. For me it was an import error.

I had the following file structure:

```
app.py
resources/__init__.py
resources/SomeResource.py
```

In app.py, I had the following code:

```
from resources import SomeResource
# ...
api.add_resource(SomeResource, '/someresource')
# ...
```

The error was due to the import line. It should have been:

```
from resources.SomeResource import SomeResource
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But it's horrible! Why does it even let the import through if it doesn't exist? I wasted too much time on this.

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem - didn't occurred to me that this is even the direction - thank you

Comment: This was perfectly helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was due to duplicate view name in regular flask views and rest-full Resource views.

For example in routes.py

```
@products.route('/api/products', methods=['GET'])
def items():
    "some code here"
```

In Rest-full apis.py

```
class Items(Resource):
    def get(self):
        "Some code here"


api.add_resource(Items, '/hello')
```

When i changed one of the name of view then its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread, but if you really use f-restful package of that version (~0.8.0), than maybe could be a bug.

Otherwise, for every newcomer, use the new way of importing the **Resource** class:
[See the official docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Resource)

It says:

> class flask_restful.Resource

while you shouldn't use as: *from flask.ext.restful import Resource*,
what means

> flask.ext.restful.Resource